# The weak law of large numbers from the central limit theorem.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

I could not derive the weak law of large numbers from the central limit theorem for i.i.d. random variables with $0 < \operatorname{Var}(X) < \infty$.

The central limit theorem gives
$$\frac{\sum X_i - n\cdot E(X_1)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)n})} \to N(0,1)$$

Now I want to show

$$\lim P\left(\middle|\frac{\sum X_i - E(X_1)}{n}\middle| \geq \epsilon\right) = 0 \quad\forall \epsilon>0$$

I know that the cdf converges pointwise. It should be really easy as it is intuitively clear that it should hold, but I can't find the correct way to write and pin it down.

Comment: One can prove the wlln [using Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_Chebyshev.27s_inequality), and one doesn't need any nontrivial information about the shape of the distribution.

Comment: Yes. But it is asked for how to derive it from the much stronger central limit theorem..

Comment: I understand the question. What I don't understand is why the CLT should be of much use here.

Answer (score 4):

For every positive $t$, consider the events $A_n^t=[|S_n-nE[X]|\geqslant t\sqrt{n\mathrm{var}(X)}]$ and $B_n^t=[|S_n-nE[X]|\geqslant nt]$. Then:

1. The CLT says that $P[A_n^t]\to P[|Z|\geqslant t]$ when $n\to\infty$, for every positive $t$, where $Z$ is standard normal.
2. The WLLN says that $P[B_n^t]\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, for every positive $t$.
3. For every positive $t$ and $s$, there exists some finite $N$ such that $B_n^t\subseteq A_n^s$ for every $n$ large enough (*can you show this?*).

With these elementary facts in mind, assume that 1. holds, that is, that the CLT is valid and consider some positive $t$ and $\varepsilon$. Then:

- There exists some finite $s$ such that $P[|Z|\geqslant s]\leqslant\varepsilon$.
- By 1., this implies that $P[A_n^s]\leqslant2\varepsilon$ for every $n$ large enough, say $n\geqslant N_1$.
- By 3., $P[B_n^t]\leqslant P[A_n^s]$ for every $n$ large enough, say $n\geqslant N_2$.

Thus, for every $n\geqslant\max(N_1,N_2)$, $P[B_n^t]\leqslant2\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, this is the WLLN.